# How to change background image of tab bar item in ios?

Tags: ios, uiimage, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I want to change the background of tab bar item with some image .
Can anyone help me out in this regard?

Here is what i wanted :

[image]

Also i need to know what should be the size of background image . My images are getting out of bound

[image]

Comment: You need to implement `AutoLayout` that solve your problem.

Comment: Managing tab bar customization will give some limitations, instead try to use customized tab bar with custom view and buttons on it!

Answer (score 2):

To change background colour of `UITabBar`

```
TabBarController* Tcontroller =(TabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController;
Tcontroller.tabBar.barTintColor=[UIColor greenColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

you should calculate your image size for your tabbaritem by yourself, based on its quantity, for example if you have 4 tab items: the width of every item will be 1/4 of screen width and the height is a tablet height.